# Payload document size is larger than maximum of 16793600

Tags: java, mongodb

While storing  the data in mongodb, sometimes the value of a key which is string data type in a document is very huge and hence causing this error as : Payload document size is larger than maximum of 16793600.

Can we use gridsFs to resolve this or is there any alternate solution?

Comment: MongoDB has 16 MB document size limit. You can use GridFS for storing large sized data.

Comment: @prasad_ , How to use GridFs when we are not storing the data in the form of a separate file? Or is there any other alternative for this

Comment: See this [MongoDB Java GridFS](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver/tutorials/gridfs/).